# CSS media queries scale

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with media queries

I have an element div

```
.my-div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

I scale it down at 850px

```
@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .my-div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

But when on a screen with a size of 800px I reduce the screen scale by 10%, then the media query stops working and the element becomes large.
It is noticeable that the element was small, and then it became larger and only then it becomes smaller if you continue to reduce the scale

I understand that when you zoom out, the browser increases the width of the window and the media query stops working

but maybe there is some way to avoid this?

Comment: Zoom means to zoom stuff and user has end control over how the site renders. What exactly do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: You have to have in mind that when you zoom out our zoom in you are modifying the screen size (in this case, incrementing 10% of 800px to 880px), so for that reason your media query isn't 'working'

Comment: At 90% zoom your page probably has more than 1920px, which is why none of your queries apply. You don't have a default case. You could add fixed width for that case.
eg. 

.screenWidth {
    width: 960px;
}